# Visual Basic "with block" equivalent in Julia?

Tags: julia

I know in various programming languages there is a block syntax to simplifies expressions that have too much references to the fields of an object

e.g. in VB one can use **with block** whith following description:

> By using With...End With, you can perform a series of statements on a
>   specified object without specifying the name of the object multiple
>   times. Within a With statement block, you can specify a member of the
>   object starting with a period, as if the With statement object
>   preceded it.

I want to do something like this in Julia:

```
With theCustomer
    .Name = "Coho Vineyard"
    .URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
    .City = "Redmond"
End With
```

or maybe:
    `@With data .a=.b+c*d`

Is there a With block equivalent in Julia?

Answer (score 8):

There is not, but you can just create a variable with a short name instead. If you also want to limit the scope in the same way as above, you can do e.g.

```
let c = theCustomer
    c.Name = "Coho Vineyard"
    c.URL = "http://www.cohovineyard.com/"
    c.City = "Redmond"
end
```

Not much more verbose, and doesn't require special syntax.

Comment: I came from F#. I started to abuse `let` the first second I learnt its existence in julia.